# Inline SVG with .html extension displays correctly, with .svg extension it doesn't

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a pie-chart SVG generated by d3. If
I save the content in a file with .svg extension
none of the browsers are able to display it.

If I save the same content in a file with 
extension .html, it gets displayed fine.

Why ?

The SVG content is here http://pastebin.com/9QPKT5ju

To add to more detail, there is no web server involved,
just saving the content in a file with .html extension
& loading the file in browser makes it display correctly, 
while changing the extension to .svg & reloading it in 
browser makes it disappear.

The reason I am doing this, is that I am generating the
svg using Node.js on server side & want to embed the
generated svg in a html page & a PDF file. For the above
experiment I just wanted to see if generated svg displays
properly in browser as it would be loaded dynamically in
a fixed HTML template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following to the base svg element:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

Your color definitions also need to be like this:

```
<radialGradient id="grad-0" cx="0" cy="0" r="190"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#ace98c"></stop><stop offset="0.3" stop-color="#ace98c"></stop><stop offset="1" stop-color="#70c046"></stop></radialGradient>
```

instead of `radialgradient` (i.e. the camel casing [is important](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#CaseSensitivity).)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the namespace to svg element, but on loading the file in browser, I see a black circle. Please see the additional details I added to the question. My question is why the graph displays fine with .html extension & without making any Camel Case change ?

Comment: SVG defines the graphics in XML format, and as such it is quite strict. I have no inside information about chrome's or chromium's leniency with regards to svg elements in the dom, but HTML5 is case INSENSITIVE. Can you adjust your server side code to follow the correct casing for the elements and see if it outputs well formed svg xml?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed radialGradient to camel case & it is being displayed correctly. So, it seems that d3 is not generating the tags in standard manner.

Comment: On further investigation I found that problem is not with d3 but jsdom which I am using to run d3 server side which is changing tag names to lower case. I applied the patch at,  https://github.com/dragansah/jsdom/commit/dded2ce487f4dbfde78ee0bc4dd6fa98511fdbff & am able to continue.

Comment: Ah, that's good, I couldn't replicate it just using d3 by itself - it always respected the case I gave it.