# Local file displays correctly with .html extension, but not with .svg extension

Tags: html, svg

I have a local file with the below content that displays correctly in Firefox and Edge when it has the .html extension, but not when it has the .svg extension. It also does not display correctly in Inkscape.

I have looked up all relevant elements and attributes on the Mozilla reference and I've asked ChatGPT both for improvements on the code as well as for possible causes for this problem. Also I've searched this site. There is [one very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800900/inline-svg-with-html-extension-displays-correctly-with-svg-extension-it-doesn), but the suggested solution did not work. I have used F12 web developer tools in both browsers. I have tried variations like leaving out the CDATA tags

To broaden the scope, what are some tools to check SVG code? What kind of fixes do browsers apply when the open SVG as HTML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="800" width="600" viewbox="0.0 0 0.9384465146064759 0.504">
  <style>
    <![CDATA[
    .color0 { fill: #b1fbdb; }
    .color0_failed { fill: #b1fbdb; stroke: red; stroke-width: 0.0005; }
    .color1 { fill: #afe1ff; }
    .color1_failed { fill: #afe1ff; stroke: red; stroke-width: 0.0005; }
    ]]>
    </style>
  <rect id="a-0" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="0.13119802236557007" height="0.01" rx="0.001" class="color0"/>
  <rect id="a-1" x="0.0" y="0.0105" width="0.16152658224105834" height="0.01" rx="0.001" class="color0_failed"/>
  <rect id="a-25" x="0.06276478767395019" y="0.14700000000000002" width="0.12046767950057984" height="0.01" rx="0.001" class="color1"/>
  <rect id="a-26" x="0.06276478767395019" y="0.1575" width="0.0905509090423584" height="0.01" rx="0.001" class="color1"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Why bother with the `style`? I'd just inline that information as attributes (i.e., `fill="#b1fbdb"` on the one `rect` that uses `class="color0"`. BTW, it's off-topic to ask for tools on Stack Overflow, so I'd remove that question. Just ask how to get the SVG working as a standalone file.

Comment: SVG is case sensitive and it's viewBox rather than viewbox. HTML is not case sensitive.